# Trying to load js file before svelte component runs

Tags: svelte, webpack-hmr

I'm trying to load a js file before my Svelte component runs and I'm trying to do it this way:

```
    <script>
  //prettier-ignore
  let press = 1200,temp = 25,rho = 0;
  //prettier-ignore
  function density() {
      const dens = Module.PropsSI("D","P",+press * 6894.75729,"T",+273.15 + temp,"Xenon");
    rho = dens;
    resolve(dens); // immediately
  }
</script>

<svelte:head>
  <script src="../public/coolprop.js" on:load={density}></script>
</svelte:head>

<main>
  {#await rho}
    <h1>Loading...</h1>
  {:then value}
    <p>Pressure is {press}, temperature is {temp}, density is {value}</p>
  {/await}
</main>
```

But I'm getting error like this:

```
Failed to init component
<App3>

create_fragment@http://localhost:8080/build/bundle.js:9218:5
init@http://localhost:8080/build/bundle.js:11084:37
App3@http://localhost:8080/build/bundle.js:9295:56
createProxiedComponent@http://localhost:8080/build/bundle.js:9075:9
ProxyComponent@http://localhost:8080/build/bundle.js:8648:92
Proxy<App3>@http://localhost:8080/build/bundle.js:8740:11
./src/main.js@http://localhost:8080/build/bundle.js:13659:13
__webpack_require__@http://localhost:8080/build/bundle.js:13696:33
@http://localhost:8080/build/bundle.js:14852:30
@http://localhost:8080/build/bundle.js:14856:12
```

What is the right way to do this? I know this code works when I use coolprop.js from index.html but was running into an issue where only on code chage will HMR trigger right answer and hence this approach. Any suggestions are welcome! I've been breaking my head to figure this out..
thanks, gani-

---

ok, I tried to load coolprop.js before component is run but apparently it doesn't work. Here is code I tried.

```
<script>
  //prettier-ignore
  let press = 1200,temp = 25,rho=0;
  //prettier-ignore

  //prettier-ignore
  function prop (){
  let promise2 = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    const dens = Module.PropsSI("D","P",+press * 6894.75729,"T",+273.15 + temp,"Xenon");
    rho = dens;
   // resolve(dens); // immediately
  });
}
  //prettier-ignore
  function prop1() {
    const dens = Module.PropsSI("D","P",+press * 6894.75729,"T",+273.15 + temp,"Xenon");
    rho = dens;
    console.log("rho inside prop1 is ", rho);
  }
  // onMount(test1);
</script>

<svelte:head>
  <script src="coolprop.js" on:load={prop1}></script>
</svelte:head>


<main>
  {#await rho}
    <h1>Loading...</h1>
  {:then value}
    <p>Pressure is {press}, temperature is {temp}, density is {value}</p>
  {/await}
</main>
```

It doesn't seem to matter if I use function as promise or not. I only get it to work when I tweak the code when running in dev more and HMR takes care of the change and it works.

I think there is some subtle bug and it is bugging me :) I think a Svelte guru input is in order now...

gani -

Answer (score 0):

Can you not import like this:

```
<script>
  import Whatever from '../public/coolprop.js';
  const value= Whatever.density()

</script>

<h1> density is {value}<</h1>
```